# Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog

Tags: apache-2.2, https, phusion-passenger

I'm trying to install Passenger (mod_rails) on Apache2 server by using the command

```
1. gem install passenger
2. passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Passenger gets installed and i added the below line to my configuration file

> LoadModule passenger_module
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/pass
>   enger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
>   PassengerRoot /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.11
>   PassengerRuby /home/ec2-user/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p290/ruby

Once i finished all those steps and i started accessing of [Apache2 server](https://www.example.com).

I got the following Passenger error:

> [error] *** Passenger could not be initialized because of this error:
>   Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because its exec utable
>   (/usr/lib/phusion-passenger/agents/PassengerWatchdog) does not exist.
>   Thi s probably means that your Phusion Passenger installation is
>   broken or incomplet e, or that your 'PassengerRoot' directive is set
>   to the wrong value. Please rein stall Phusion Passenger or fix your
>   'PassengerRoot' directive, whichever is appl icable.

After getting this error, i `re-installed Passenger` once again with those steps but still this problem remains the same.

Appreciate your help in resolving this issue.

Comment: It takes PassengerRoot path as (/usr/lib/phusion-passenger/agents/PassengerWatchdog) instead of (/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.11). Why?

Answer (score 1):

First, let us make sure Watchdog is present on the system by running: `find / -name PassengerWatchdog`

Then if it's an RVM issue, you can try a workaround of symliking Passenger's root to the location mentioned by apache:

```
ln -s  /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.11 /usr/lib/phusion-passenger
```

On another hand, are you sure running `passenger-install-apache2-module` didn't raise any errors/warnings? including its output to the question could be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same config in Ubuntu and CentOS. Any chance there is an existing Passenger installation on the system that is interfering. If so, delete it and restart Apache.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response! I did above you said, but still it remains the same problem.

Comment: Odd. I guess the next step is to go through the Apache conf files and make sure only the rvm Passenger is getting loaded.

Comment: Yes, module passenger_module is getting loaded.....

Comment: I am having a similar problem.  Using RVM, Apache 2.2.20 on Ubuntu; I have checked that passenger is only getting loaded using RVM modules.  When I start Apache it hangs while loading PassengerWatchdog.